# How can I fix my canvas since it isn't rendering the spline file?

Tags: canvas, rendering, spline

my spline scene does not render like supposed to after following the steps in the spline docs, anyone know why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css"/>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas3d"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import { Application } from '@splinetool/runtime';

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas3d');
const app = new Application(canvas);
app.load('https://prod.spline.design/xYRGh6oAi1HPkF-x/scene.splinecode');
```

Comment: It could happen because you execute the script before the canvas is loaded. You can prevent that by using `defer`, for example `<script defer src="app.js"></script>`

Comment: @Kokodoko just tried it, still didn't work, thank you for the suggestion though :)

Comment: When you use `import`, the spline library has to be available on your own environment, see: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@splinetool/runtime`. But you can also create a viewer using `<script>` tags, see: https://viewer.spline.design

Comment: @Kokodoko my goal is to use gsap for animation on my spline scene, embedding the scene into my code won't let me use it I think, I may be wrong I'm still new to all of this. Also I already installed @splinetool/runtime

Comment: In the code you posted, you use `import { Application } from '@splinetool/runtime';` but it's not clear to me where you are importing from.

Comment: @Kokodoko when exporting from spline that's the code it told me to use, as shown in this link you sent me too https://www.npmjs.com/package/@splinetool/runtime

Comment: When you run `npm install @splinetool/runtime` you install the module in your local development environment. You can then use that library with `import { Application } from '@splinetool/runtime';`, but that only works when you use a tool that bundles the npm module in your application. For example, you could use Vite or Parcel to bundle your application. Those tools use the command `npm run build`. In your case, it seems like you are not bundling your modules, that's why the library doesn't run.

Comment: And if you don't want to use a module bundler, you can also load the library using a script tag: `<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@splinetool/viewer/build/spline-viewer.js"></script>` and load the viewer with 
`<spline-viewer url="https://prod.spline.design/UWoeqiir20o49Dah/scene.splinecode"></spline-viewer>`